# Elastic Beanstalk with CloudWatch logs and Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have activated the CloudWatch logs in my EBS Application. I have enabled like screenshot attached:

[image]

But when I look in awslogs.log, I can find all the time this error:

```
cwlogs.push.stream - WARNING - 3317 - Thread-1 - No file is found with given path '/var/log/httpd/error.log*'.
cwlogs.push.stream - WARNING - 3317 - Thread-1 - No file is found with given path '/var/log/httpd/access.log*'.
```

I don't know why, because httpd is a service from Apache, and I'm working with Nginx (with Node.js as origin).

How can I disable/remove this error?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same error with catalina.out file. It is in the location specified in awslogs.config but agent says: No file is found with given path. But when I open the file manually (catalina.out) and add something to the beginning and save, the agent starts to see it and streams the logs. Any Idea?

Comment: @hyeganeh touching the catalina.out file will fix that. I don't know if this is a bug in elastic beanstalk but I suggest an .ebextensions workaround in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the `awslogs` application on your EC2 instance is looking for those files to send to the CloudWatch.

You can check and edit the configuration file located at:

```
/etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf
```

Make sure to restart the service:

```
sudo service awslogs restart
```

You can specify your own files there and create different groups and what not.

Resources:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `.ebextensions/awslog.config`:

```
container_commands:
  touch_logs:
    command: touch /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log /var/log/nginx/access.log /var/log/nginx/error.log /var/log/httpd/access_log /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

This ensures you never see the "No file is found with given path" for any of these files.

Note: If you're using a container other than node, you can replace `/var/log/nodejs.log` with whatever is found in beanstalklogs.conf...

---

The awslogs config file is `/etc/awslogs/config/beanstalklogs.conf`, the default (for Node):

```
[/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log]
log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/YOUR_ENV/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
log_stream_name={instance_id}
file=/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log*

[/var/log/nginx/error.log]
log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/YOUR_ENV/var/log/nginx/error.log
log_stream_name={instance_id}
file=/var/log/nginx/error.log*

[/var/log/nginx/access.log]
log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/YOUR_ENV/var/log/nginx/access.log
log_stream_name={instance_id}
file=/var/log/nginx/access.log*

[/var/log/httpd/error_log]
log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/YOUR_ENV/var/log/httpd/error_log
log_stream_name={instance_id}
file=/var/log/httpd/error_log*

[/var/log/httpd/access_log]
log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/YOUR_ENV/var/log/httpd/access_log
log_stream_name={instance_id}
file=/var/log/httpd/access_log*

[/var/log/eb-activity.log]
log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/YOUR_ENV/var/log/eb-activity.log
log_stream_name={instance_id}
file=/var/log/eb-activity.log*
```

As you can see this has *both* nginx and httpd lines.

One could either:
1. remove these httpd blocks.
2. touch these files.

Touching these files seems less invasive and suppresses the error messages so nothing is posted to cloudwatch logs:

```
sudo touch /var/log/httpd/error_log /var/log/httpd/access_log
```

Note: When EB first boots up you get errors for httpd, nginx and nodejs.log! So it seems easier to touch all of these files at boot time, which is what the awslog.config file above does.

Comment: I tested this answer with our java elastic beanstalk apps and it works (replacing `/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log` with `/var/log/tomcat8/debug.log`).

Comment: I tested this answer on a nodes instance and it didn't work, just keep showing same errors

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this problem is to change `/etc/awslogs/config/beanstalklogs.conf` file.

You can create an `.ebextensions/myconfig.config` file that contains the following contents:

```
files:
  "/etc/awslogs/config/beanstalklogs.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log]
      log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/YOUR_ENV/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
      log_stream_name={instance_id}
      file=/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log*

      [/var/log/nginx/error.log]
      log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/YOUR_ENV/var/log/nginx/error.log
      log_stream_name={instance_id}
      file=/var/log/nginx/error.log*

      [/var/log/nginx/access.log]
      log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/YOUR_ENV/var/log/nginx/access.log
      log_stream_name={instance_id}
      file=/var/log/nginx/access.log*

      # [/var/log/httpd/error_log]
      # log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/YOUR_ENV/var/log/httpd/error_log
      # log_stream_name={instance_id}
      # file=/var/log/httpd/error_log*

      # [/var/log/httpd/access_log]
      # log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/YOUR_ENV/var/log/httpd/access_log
      # log_stream_name={instance_id}
      # file=/var/log/httpd/access_log*

      [/var/log/eb-activity.log]
      log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/YOUR_ENV/var/log/eb-activity.log
      log_stream_name={instance_id}
      file=/var/log/eb-activity.log*
commands:
  01-remove-default-beanstalklogs:
    command: rm /etc/awslogs/config/beanstalklogs.conf.bak
  02-restart-awslogs:
    command: service awslogs restart
```

Note that I have commented out the lines for uploading `/var/log/httpd/error.log*` and `/var/log/httpd/access.log*` files. So CloudWatch agent will stop looking for these files.

Awslogs uses the default `beanstalklogs.conf` mentioned by @AndyHayden before running the commands in `myconfig.config`. That's why I ask awslogs to restart after `beanstalklogs.conf` file is changed.

Place `.ebextensions/myconfig.config` in the `*.zip` file that you uploaded to elastic beanstalk. Then elastic beanstalk will execute the commands in `myconfig.config`.

Here is the document for the usage of `commands`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue in one of my environment and I was facing this issue with the environment where there was autoscaling of instances configured and that too in the environment where there was too frequent scaling happening.

Looked at the awslogs in /var/logs dir and it had this error

> cwlogs.push.stream - WARNING - 3317 - Thread-1 - No file is found with given path '/var/log/production.log*'.

I tried creating a file using the command

> sudo touch /var/log/production.log

But that stopped the errors but that did not stream the logs even after restarting.

And finally looking at the other instances where there was a log streaming properly, it was symbolic link to the file where the actual log was being returned and so created a symbolic link from the ebextension through container command

```
commands:
  "01":
    command: ln -sf /var/app/current/log/production.log /var/log/production.log
```

This worked for me finally.